# Expression Result Unused Error in Xcode

Tags: objective-c

Why am I getting this error?

```
if(appDelegate.lastLevelIndex!=0) {
        [self.view addSubview:creditView];
        NSString *level=[NSString stringWithFormat:(@"%d",appDelegate.lastLevelIndex)];
        label.text=level;
        appDelegate.lastLevelIndex=0;
    }
```

I also get a crash here due to the original error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the parentheses here:

```
NSString *level=[NSString stringWithFormat:(@"%d",appDelegate.lastLevelIndex)];
                                           ^                                ^
```

Resulting in:

```
NSString *level=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",appDelegate.lastLevelIndex];
```

---

The method `stringWithFormat:` expects a list of comma-separated arguments. The first argument is a format string that serves as a template into which the remaining argument values are substituted.

With the parentheses in place, however, you are passing a single argument to `stringWithFormat:`, the result of evaluating the expression contained within the parentheses.

```
(@"%d",appDelegate.lastLevelIndex)
      ^
```

In C and, by extension, Objective-C a list of expressions separated by a [comma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) is evaluated left to right, and the type and value of the result are the type and value of the right operand.

Therefore, you are passing the value of `appDelegate.lastLevelIndex`, an integer, as the only argument to the `stringWithFormat:` method, which expects a `NSString *`. Hence, the crash. The "Expression Result Unused" warning is due to the fact that the left expression `@"%d"` has no effect.